# Taxation of foreign capital gains for Indian residents

Tags: taxes, india, capital-gains-tax

How are capital gains on specifically foreign stocks taxed in India for Indian residents? Are they added to income and taxed at ordinary tax rates? If yes, can capital losses be deducted from ordinary income? Or are capital gains taxed at different rates?

Answer (score 1):

Capital gains are taxed at 10% for short term and 20% for long term (holding more than a year).

The taxes are applicable if overall taxable income is above taxable threshold. I.e if you are only making say Rs 2,50,000 Including capital gains,  no taxes...

Comment: Thank you. Are these rates applicable to foreign capital gains too? Are capital gains taxed separately? What about capital losses? Are you sure that the short term capital gains tax rate is less than the long term rate?

Comment: So there is no incentive to holding stocks for long term, then?